Protagonist fails psychological evaluation for politicians
I'm remembering a story from Analog, I think, about a near-future politician running for Senate (or some other major office). It is accepted practice (perhaps not legally required) for a particular psychological test to be given to all candidates, which evaluates their personality, and the politician (a lawyer in his non-political life, a partner in a major firm) is evaluated as being fundamentally self-centered - not criminal, but someone who would put his interests above the public interest. His advisors recognize this as a deathblow to his campaign, and advise him to quit; afterwards, he tries to find something to do with his life, while also dealing with the unpleasant fact of his evaluation. I think he goes to therapy - he definitely adopts a puppy (initially to look better, I think), and becomes a happier and better person (not that he ever was a particularly bad one - just a bit cold). I think it's a 1990s era story that I read much later when I got a collection of Analogs in the 2000s.

Yeah but if he is ... evaluated as being fundamentally self-centered, then he'd be a perfect politician right?  A much better twist would have been that he gets evaluated as being someone who genuinely wants to helps others and therefore is disqualified from the process.

You have a point.

To quote Douglass Adams: "Anyone who is capable of getting themselves made President should on no account be allowed to do the job."

Slowly, Slowly in the Wind by Rob Chilson, a novelette from Analog, April 1984
Can't find it online, but picked up a copy of the issue at a recent con.
Jim Richardson loses the election (but doesn't quit the race) due in large part to the "psychometric evaluation" that is done shallowly due to a review of his public behavior - and  which condemns him as honest but shallow and self-serving to a high degree.
After his defeat, he takes a full evaluation (requiring an EEG and "Voigt-Kampf pupilometry (heh!)), and learns a bit about himself - and he does get a puppy, which symbolizes his decision to try to grow up as a person.
